# link_to_route('pages.create') doesn't work in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, url, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have a problem within my routes. here is the error meesage "Route [pages.create] not defined".
this my **show.blade.php**:

```
 {{ link_to_route('pages.create','page2')}}
```

**routes.php**

```
 Route::resource('page', 'PagesController');
```

PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('pages.show');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return "hai";
    }

    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your routes.php file probably you have not defined the route for pages.create

Answer (score 1):

It should be `{{ route('page.create','page2')}}`

When a resource generates routes it does not make them plural. So the routes available would be `page.create`, `page.show`, `page.store`, etc.

Also your PageController.php should be named `KerjasamasController.php` to be loaded properly and everything referencing PageController should be updated to `KerjasamasController`. I would read more about how PSR-4 autoloading works.

Comment: Updated. Your controller isn't being referenced properly.

Comment: This was changed to `route`.

Answer (score 1):

> Please Try Here Laravel Function {{ HTML::linkRoute('pages.create', 'page2' }}
>
> It Properly Work in laravel4.2

Answer (score 0):

When using the resource route method , route names are in this format:

```
'your_url.index',
'your_url.create',
'your_url.store',
'your_url.edit',
'your_url.update',
'your_url.destroy'
```

In your example you should replace 'pages' with 'page'

Answer (score 0):

just try to add the value in the after type method of your route
and go to any method from the controller

- index
- edit
- create
- show
- store
- update
- destroy